# How can I determine what Github repo identifier I need in order to check out my specific Ubuntu Linux Kernel version?

Tags: linux, kernel

How can I determine what Github repo identifier (Branch/label/whatever..) I need in order to check out my specific Ubuntu Linux Kernel version ?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Using Term, if I do a $ uname -r  I get "4.13.0-37-generic"
But if I go to https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master
I cant find 4.13.0-37-generic ANYWHERE, or make a correct determination which label/branch I need, without gussing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu kernel package is hosted on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux), and you’ll find the relevant code there.

However, like any package in Ubuntu (and any Debian derivative), the best way to get a package’s source code is to use the package management system:

```
apt source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

will download the kernel source code as packaged for your distribution, and

```
debcheckout linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

(from the `devscripts` package) will give you a clone of the relevant repository.

Comment: No dice, my system is new.
It  was completed successfully yesterday. So its, fresh.  
I ran $ apt source linux  and it said
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
So, I went to https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/293888
and did a "sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" I tried again and got the same error. I went to the GUI Ubuntu Software Center and could find nothing about kernel sources.I need my version of kernel sources. What can I do ?

Comment: I dont know what URL or URI's or what ever to add to that sources file ?

Comment: On a vanilla Ubuntu install, you should have commented-out `deb-src` entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  Uncomment to use.

Comment: No dice, I uncommented every valid line in that file. I also have looked for a valid sources.list which seems like it should have been updated in this distro version. I am assuming that this is the actual problem. I would think that the module that reads that file hopefully does not have a defect. I just dont know what to do.

Comment: You need two lines, one saying `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main`, the other `deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main`; see [the Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html). Once you’ve updated your `sources.list`, you need to run `sudo apt update` before you can install software or download source code from the repositories.

Comment: Ok, that worked ! I did haft to use the command "apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)" because the ones above seemed to give me v4.4.0
without auto patching up my version. Thank you !